# How does entropy help decide the spontaneity of a reaction?

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy, physical-chemistry

Consider the endothermic reaction:

$$2\ CH_3COOH\ (l)+(NH_4)_2CO_3\ (s) \to CH_3COONH_4\ (aq)+CO_2\ (g)+H_2O\ (l)$$

This reaction is spontaneous despite being endothermic because the entropy change is sufficiently positive.

I don't understand how the entropy change can effect the spontaneity of a reaction. The molecules are just bumping around, how do they know that the products can occupy more microstates for a given macrostate?

Is the entropy just an complicated way of saying that (due to more microstates) the product molecules are less likely to be in the same neighborhood of each other in order to react and reform the reactants? If so, why not just say that?

At a molecular level, why does higher entropy products lead to spontaneous reactions?

Comment: Higher entropy means higher probability. The system obviously will tend to find itself in the most probable of states. Imagine you build a small sandcastle on the beach. Now observe it over time. Over time it loses its shape and structure, until it's merely a heap of sand. As it happens the undifferentiated heap of sand has much higher probability than the structured, shapely sandcastle.

Comment: In the case of your reaction, the RHS is more entropic, largely because of the gas: gasses have no structure and thus are of very high entropy.

Comment: You should also read up on Gibbs Free Energy, $\Delta G$, if you haven't already.

Comment: @Gert But doesn't this probability argument only hold if all states are constantly swapping? Sure, the gas has more entropy but the chemicals bumping into each other don't know that. This is why it makes sense that the enthalpy has a role in determining spontaneity. I have read about Gibbs free energy and how it's really just the Second Law in disguise, but I'm failing to see the entropy part play it's role. Shouldn't the system be sampling all possible states in order to transition to the most probable?

Comment: Again, as this is cross posted. They are not inert spheres bumping around.

Comment: *But doesn't this probability argument only hold if all states are constantly swapping?* Actually, they are. All reactions are equilibria.

Comment: @Alchimista That single sentence explanation doesn't even try to answer the question, it's just a nitpick about how i'm presenting the question. How does correcting for the fact that they aren't inert spheres bumping around explain (at a molecular level) why higher entropy products dictates the spontaneity of a reaction?

Comment: Because they are not just bumping around but reacting. It is simply so I do not nitpick anything. It is the assumption that is wrong. They are not just bumping around but reacting. I think this is enough to see how the above reaction does spontaneously occurs in the light of a probability argument. Besides, did you check for its enthalpy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is the entropy just an complicated way of saying that (due to more microstates) the product molecules are less likely to be in the same neighborhood of each other in order to react and reform the reactants?

No, what you are describing is purely a kinetic effect.

> The molecules are just bumping around, how do they know that the products can occupy more microstates for a given macrostate?

They don't.  Entropy doesn't apply at the level of individual molecules. [There are exceptions with very large molecules, but addressing those would require a much higher-level of discussion not appropriate for the OP.]  Rather, it is an emergent statistical property that manifests itself when we have a sufficiently large collection of molecules such that, when we apply a stastistical treatment, the probabilities overwhelmingly favor a single macrostate.

More specifically, the entropy of a system is proportional (through Boltzmann's constant) to the log of the number of possible macroscopically indistinguishable microstates that a system in a given macrostate can sample, weighted by the relative probabilities of those microstates.

As a consequence, if you allow a molecular species additional degrees of freedom (e.g., vibrational), then a collection of those molecules would have many more ways in which they could arrange themselves, giving you a relatitively higher probability of seeing those molecules -- i.e., favoring them entropically.

A rough analogy would be this:

Suppose you have a white ball, a black ball, and three wells.  The white ball can only go in well no 1, while the black ball can go into either well no. 2 or well no. 3 (i.e., the black ball has double the possible ways it can arrange itself).

Each time you push a button, you allow the balls to go into their wells. Each ball has a 10% chance of making it into a well.  Thus each time you push the button, there is a 10% of a white ball appearing (because it has only one possible configuration) (one well), but a 1-.9^2 = 19% chance of a black ball appearing (because it has two possible configurations) (two wells).  The black ball and white ball have no idea what each other are doing.  Yet, when you consider the system as a whole, you are more likely to see results that have a black ball than results that have a white ball.  Thus the "equilbrium", averaged over many games, favors the black ball.

Comment: So the argument is that the products of the above reaction have more microstates, so if you "push the button" you're more likely to find the molecules as products rather than reactants. There are more states of the system where the molecules are product instead of reactant (in this case). I hope this is a correct interpretation of your answer. But doesn't this answer imply that the system is constantly sampling all the possible states of the system, which is why you find it in the most probable? Surely it doesn't sample ALL possible states, plus it's less likely to be found in higher E states?

Comment: @dljs Yes, up where you said "I hope this is a correct interpretation" is correct, with the caveat that here we're only accounting for the effect of the difference between the *entropies* of the reactants and products upon their relative probabilities.   The enthalpy difference also contributes to the relative probability of having reactants vs. products, since what determines spontaneity is the entropy change of the universe, i.e., of the system + surroundings, and the entropy change of the surroundings, at constant T and p, is equal to $-\Delta H_{sys}/T$....

Comment: ....Hence, at const. T and p, $\Delta G_{sys} = \Delta H_{sys} - T \Delta S _{sys} = - T \times (\Delta S_{surr} + \Delta S_{sys}) = -T \Delta S_{univ}$.  [For more on this, see the bottom of my answer at https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/124412/what-is-wrong-in-this-argument-that-dg-must-always-be-zero/124470#124470]

Comment: As to the latter part of your comment, according to the ergodic hypothesis (which underlies stat mech), the sys. is able to eventually sample all possible states (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ergodic_theory). As to what % of possible configs. the sys. needs to sample to represent the equil. state, and how long that sampling would take, that gets into a separate ques. Finally, if you allow energetic fluctuations (say, if it's @ constant T), then the higher-energy states are less likely, but that's built into the entropy calc.

Comment: So if we isolated this reaction, would the spontaneity be solely determined by the change in entropies between the products and reactants (no delta S for surroundings)? Also, I've been picturing delta H to be the change in energy between reactants vs products, but you say that it's built into the entropy calculation (through the probability in the Gibbs entropy formula I assume). So how to interpret delta H if it's just used to determine the entropy change of surroundings? Is it the heat release due to the reaction? Has it to do with final vs begining state energies at all?

Comment: For your 1st question, the answer is no, $\Delta H$ still matters, because now, if the rxn is, say, exothermic, the thermal energy released instead goes towards increasing the temperature of the system, thus increasing its entropy. For your 2nd ques., at const T and p,with pV work only, $\Delta H$ is indeed the heat flow into the surroundings—which is of importance in its own right, since it is often of great practical importance whether a reacting system absorbs or evolves thermal energy.  The sign and magnitude of $\Delta H$ also determines the T-dependence of the equilibrium constant.

Answer (score 0):

Consider salt dissolving in water. This is an example of a reaction that is endothermic, but still favoured at room temperature. Ions of sodium and chlorine break off of the crystal and dissolve into the water. A sodium ion might be hit by a water molecule and become detached from the salt crystal. In reverse, this looks like a sodium ion colliding with a water molecule and slowing down enough to rejoin the salt crystal. It turns out that it is pretty easy for an ion to leave the crystal, but rejoining it requires the velocities of the particles involved to coincidentally line up just right. This is because there are more states with more salt dissolved in the water, so reaching one with less dissolved salt requires properly aimed velocities. You can think about this like trying to hit a target with an arrow. The smaller the target, the more carefully you need to direct the arrow.

Comment: This answer says precious little about the reaction in question.

Comment: Does this answer apply in other scenarios (like the evolution of gas from a reaction mentioned above?). Also, why would it be easier for the salt to dissolve rather than ions to recombine with the crystal? Isn't there a 1:1 correspondence between paths of NaCl and H20 molecules hitting each other and causing the NaCl to dissolve and the Na+ and Cl- reforming the crystal? There should be a 1:1 correpondance because you can just play the dissolving process backwards in time to get a valid possible crystallization process. This implies that the forward and backward reactions are equally likely.

Answer (score 0):

According to the formulations in either the laws or the postulates forms of thermodynamics, the entropy change of a chemical reaction is NOT the deciding factor for whether the reaction is or is not spontaneous. The entropy change of **the universe** during any process determines whether the process is or is not spontaneous. The entropy change of a chemical reaction is only tracking the entropy change of the system. We must also know the entropy change of the surroundings during that chemical reaction.

Translating this to the paradigm of statistical mechanics, we must state that the number of micro states of the reactants or products has no bearing on whether the reaction is spontaneous. The difference between the number of micro states in the products versus reactants will define the entropy change of the chemical reaction. But, that is a system-level result. It tells us nothing about what has happened to the number of possible micro states in the surroundings during the reaction. If that number increases more than the number in the system, then entropy in the universe has increased, and the reaction is spontaneous.

When we want to use a system perspective in our constant (T, p) world, we turn to the Gibbs energy of a process (chemical reaction). This is the deciding factor for whether the process is or is not spontaneous. The Gibbs energy must be negative for spontaneity.

For fun, we could decide to live in a box (system) with constant internal energy and constant volume rather than constant (T, p). In that box, we would only need to track the entropy change of the system to define spontaneity. Such boxes are used for example in theoretical modeling simulations.